# bus error on usage of rusqlite with spatialite extension

Tags: sqlite, rust, spatialite, rusqlite

I'm seeing a `bus error` on `cargo run` when attempting to load the spatialite extension with rusqlite:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.19s
Running `target/debug/rust-spatialite-example`
[1]    33253 bus error  cargo run --verbose
```

My suspicion is that there's a mismatch of sqlite version and spatialite and that they need to be built together rather than using the `bundled` feature of rusqlite, though it seems like that'd result in a different error?

Here's how things are set up:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "rust-spatialite-example"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rusqlite = { version = "0.28.0", features = ["load_extension", "bundled"] }
```

**init.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE place (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('place', 'geom', 4326, 'POINT', 'XY', 0);
SELECT CreateSpatialIndex('place', 'geom');
```

**main.rs**

```
use rusqlite::{Connection, Result, LoadExtensionGuard};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Place {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
    geom: String,
}

fn load_spatialite(conn: &Connection) -> Result<()> {
    unsafe {
        let _guard = LoadExtensionGuard::new(conn)?;
        conn.load_extension("/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libspatialite/5.0.1_2/lib/mod_spatialite", None)
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let conn = Connection::open("./geo.db")?;

    load_spatialite(&conn)?;

    // ... sql statements that aren't executed

    Ok(())
}
```

**Running:**

```
cat init.sql | spatialite geo.db
cargo run
```

The mod_spatialite path is correct (there's an expected `SqliteFailure` error when that path is wrong). I tried explicitly setting `sqlite3_modspatialite_init` as the entry point and the behavior stayed the same.

Comment: on Linux (Ubuntu) I loaded modspatialite without specifying a path. Literally same code as you just: `conn.load_extension("mod_spatialite", None)`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently as well. The underlying error message I was provided was "not authorized" which eventually led me to [`load_extension_enable`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.29.0/rusqlite/struct.Connection.html#method.load_extension_enable).

I started with basically the same code as you then added calls to `load_extension_enable` (and `load_extension_disable`) which resolved the issue for me.

Here's an updated version of your `load_spatialite` function.

```rust
fn load_spatialite(conn: &Connection) -> Result<()> {
    unsafe {
        let _guard = LoadExtensionGuard::new(conn)?;
        conn.load_extension_enable()?;
        conn.load_extension("/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libspatialite/5.0.1_2/lib/mod_spatialite", None)
        conn.load_extension_disable()?;
    }
}
```